# Accessing Jenkins CI build & reports on IOS devices

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Requirement - Accessing Jenkins CI build & reports on IOS devices

Options being explored - 
Hudson Helper - http://greensopinion.blogspot.in/2009/05/hudson-helper-hudson-on-your-iphone.html
Jenkins Mobile - http://jenkins-ci.mobi

Problem statement - Can't put the Jenkins server on cloud (security issues)

Any thoughts to access Jenkins CI build & reports on IOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve the security issues, you could use a VPN to connect to the network where Jenkins is hosted.